# Why doesn't this SSL tunnel in C# work?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ssl, mono

I'm trying to build an SSL tunnel in C# that works something like `stunnel`  in client mode; i.e. forwarding unencrypted connections to encrypted connections.

Why doesn't this work?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Collections;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Teststunnel
{
    public class SslWrapper
    {
        public SslWrapper(IPEndPoint remote, int port)
        {
            listener = new TcpListener (port);
            Console.Error.WriteLine ("Established listener");
            listenport = port;
            server = remote;
            listener.Start ();
            new Thread (mainEventLoop).Start();
        }

        private TcpListener listener;

        private int listenport;

        private IPEndPoint server;

        private void mainEventLoop()
        {
        restart:
            Console.Error.WriteLine ("Waiting for connections...");
            TcpClient a = listener.AcceptTcpClient ();
            Console.Error.WriteLine ("Connection received!");
            tunnel (a);
            goto restart;
        }

        private void tunnel(TcpClient nconn)
        {
            SslStream sstrm = new SslStream (
                nconn.GetStream (),
                false);
            Console.Error.WriteLine (server.ToString());
            try
            {
                sstrm.AuthenticateAsClient (server.ToString());
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
                if (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine ("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
                nconn.Close();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my main function I am invoking this by using `new SslWrapper (new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("198.23.240.183"), 443), 9999);`. However, when I try to connect, the application crashes with:

> > Unhandled Exception:
> >     System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
> >       at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.ReadRecordBuffer (Int32 contentType, System.IO.Stream record) [0x00000] in :0 
> >       at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0

Yes, I am using Mono. However, I am sure that I have imported all the correct SSL root certificates using `mozroots`. What am I doing wrong? This is also reproducible on Microsoft .NET.

Comment: `TcpClient a = listener.AcceptTcpClient ()` makes it seem like this is server side code, `sstrm.AuthenticateAsClient ` is for clients. Using SSL that way may work in principle if you control both sides, but it sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: How would I do it then? This is essentially a middlebox, so it indeed is both server and client. It receives, say, plain HTTP requests and translates them to HTTPS requests.

Comment: Then you need to authenticate as client on the connection to your server, not to your client. I don't see you opening a TCP connection to the server.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I absolutely do not know how to do that. Also the thing is like this: `client==<unencrypted>==>my code==<encrypted>==>remote server